# What exactly mean by this Urikind.relative

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

What i am doing is i will have a datagridview when i select a row and click on show button i would like to display the image along with some information for that i written the following code

```
public partial class WpfWindow : Window
{
    private UCPersons _ucPersons;

    public WpfWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create WinForms Usercontrol and 
        // add it to the WindowsFormsHost
        _ucPersons = new UCPersons();
        winFormHost.Child = _ucPersons;

        List<Person> persons = CreateSamplePersons();
        _ucPersons.SetData(persons);


    }

    private List<Person> CreateSamplePersons()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(Person.Create("Dorababu", "Madhuranagar", "Hyd", 
            DateTime.Now.AddYears(-34), "1"));

        persons.Add(Person.Create("Krish", "Sat", "RJY",
            DateTime.Now.AddYears(-64), "2"));


        return persons;
    }

    private void btnDisplayDetails_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = _ucPersons.GetSelectedPerson();
        if (person != null)
        {
            lblName.Content = person.Name;
            lblAge.Content = person.BirthDay.ToShortDateString();
            Uri uri = new Uri( "m_" + person.ImageRef + ".jpg", 
                UriKind.Relative);
            imgPerson.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

But the same is not working if i copy and paste my images out of Bin.

So i would like to know some thing about this **UriKInd**

Comment: We need more context - what are you *doing* with this Uri?

Comment: I am creating the reference for the exact name using Uri

Comment: What do you mean by "for the exact name"? It sounds like relative URIs are going to be resolved relative to your bin directory... if you're using the exact same code but the image isn't in the bin directory, how do you expect it to be found?

Comment: Yeah it is in bin only but if out side bin how can i get that using that UriKind

Comment: You'd need to include a relative path name, e.g. "../images/person.jpg". However, I'm not sure whether WPF will allow you to step outside the current directory like that. You may need to just open a stream to the file directly, and pass the stream to BitmapFrame.Create.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Relative, as opposed to Absolute. "chicken/pot/pie.jpg" would be relative, because it's *relative* to the current directory. Whereas something like "C:/images/food/chicken/pot/pie.jpg" would be *absolute* because it's ...err... relative to the *root* of the drive.

The only real point to initializing the Uri this way is to avoid (or cause) exceptions when the uri is not well-formed; useful when the Uri is not predetermined.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131565.aspx)

> Relative and absolute URIs have different restrictions on their format. For example, a relative URI does not require a scheme or an authority. The value you specify in `uriKind` must match the type of URI passed in `uriString`. However, if [RelativeOrAbsolute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx) is specified, the URI string can be relative or absolute.

Answer (score 10):

It means it's a relative URI - but we don't know what it's relative to without you providing more information.

As an example, the URI here is relative:

```
<img src="person.jpg" />
```

... and so is this, although it's in some ways "less" relative than the previous one, as it only relies on the existing host/post/scheme rather than the current URI's path:

```
<img src="/images/person.jpg" />
```

This is absolute though - it contains *all* the information required, without any other context:

```
<img src="http://microsoft.com/images/person.jpg" />
```

From the [`UriKind` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx):

> Absolute URIs are characterized by a complete reference to the resource (example: http://www.contoso.com/index.html), while a relative Uri depends on a previously defined base URI (example: /index.html).

It's hard to say what problem you're having without more information though.