# uri relative vs absolute

Tags: c#, uri

I have some trouble with **uri** in my C# code

This is working:

```
var uri = new Uri("d:/Programozas dotNet/Ugyfel/Ugyfel.ClientWpf/Skins/MainSkin.xaml");
```

But unfortunately non of these:

```
var uri = new Uri("/Skins/MainSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Skins/MainSkin.xaml");
var uri = new Uri("Ugyfel.ClientWpf;/Skins/MainSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

IOException: Cannot locate resource 'skins/mainskin.xaml'.

How can I use **relative** uri insted of **absolute**?

Comment: @Kash and what should be the difference? the op ain't using `\\`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, you are right, it aint the verbatim

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That was a stupid misstake. The correct method is without leading "/"

```
var uri = new Uri("Skins/MainSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Thank you for your effort

Comment: Your first example of var uri = new Uri("/Skins/MainSkin.xaml", UriKind.Relative); work fine for me. An exception IS thrown if you omit the UriKind param.

Answer (score 4):

Relative Url (in WPF or any other desktop application) is relative to [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx). Usually this is the folder where your exe resides, but it can be different in VS Unit Testing environment.

I assume that in your project you have a folder called "Skins", and probably your exe is in "bin\debug".

The easiest thing to do is to set the MainSkin.xaml to be copied to the output directory (in the file properties) so you can refer to it with the name only with no path.

Answer (score 0):

`Urikind.Relative` makes sense when you are trying to access a resource in the same location where the app is located. For example, in this code, it is using an image located in the bin folder of the app.

```
private void btnDisplayDetails_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = _ucPersons.GetSelectedPerson();
        if (person != null)
        {
            lblName.Content = person.Name;
            lblAge.Content = person.BirthDay.ToShortDateString();
            Uri uri = new Uri( "m_" + person.ImageRef + ".jpg", 
                UriKind.Relative);
            imgPerson.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(uri);
        }
    }
```

Courtesy: [What exactly mean by this Urikind.relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242391/what-exactly-mean-by-this-urikind-relative)

---

Or it is also used when you already have defined a base URI. Check the [UriKind MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Absolute URIs are characterized by a complete reference to the
>   resource (example: http://www.contoso.com/index.html), while a
>   relative Uri depends on a previously defined base URI (example:
>   /index.html).