# howcan i pass a variable as a uri

Tags: c#, uri

using the code below i need to be able to pass different server names into the URI dynamically.
is there a way to do that?  i have tried to pass it as a string and i get the error listed below.  i also tried to pass it as a uri and that also errors.  If i hard code @"\myserver" into  `theNetCache.Add(new Uri(@"\myserver"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);`
it works.  I cant have it hard coded since i need to be able to dynamically create the server on the go.

```
Uri relativeUri = new Uri(@"\myserver", UriKind.Relative);
string url =@"\myserver";



            NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    
            CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
            theNetCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
```

> System.UriFormatException   HResult=0x80131537   Message=Invalid URI:
> The format of the URI could not be determined.   Source=test PDF
> StackTrace:    at test_PDF.openPDF.showPDF() in C:\Code\test PDF\test
> PDF\openPDF.aspx.cs:line 44    at
> test_PDF.openPDF.btnTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Code\test PDF\test PDF\openPDF.aspx.cs:line 146

Comment: So what you're saying is that when you don't specify `UriKind.Relative`, then the URI class isn't able to determine the URI format, and when you do specify `UriKind.Relative`, then the URI class knows what the URI format is?

Comment: This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203583/uri-relative-vs-absolute)

Comment: What kind of Uri uses a single backslash at the start? Are you trying to use a UNC style `\\MyServer`, or relative style `/MyServer`??